Consideration of parallel impedances in fault calculations
Hi guys I am performing a fault level calculation in an electrical power network. I know that I need to find the sum of all the upstream series impedances between the generator and the fault location. What if there is a part of the circuit that is in parallel to where the fault occurs? Do I factor in the impedance of this part of the network or can it be assumed to be zero? See picture - would I need to factor in the motor branch when calculating fault currents A and B?

Using your diagram, please add/highlight the parallel circuit.
